# Terminology: what is the precise definition of "type expression" in Haskell, as used in Thompson's book?

Tags: haskell, types, expression, terminology

What is the precise definition of the term "type expression" as used in Thompson's "Haskell - the craft of functional programming" book ? It seems that this term is not defined in the book.

It is for example not listed in the index. Also, I tried to search for a clear explicit definition in the book but found nothing.

Related question: is a `type variable` a `type expression`?

Let's consider for example the following type (expression?):

`a->b`

Now, if I replace `a` with `c`, then will `c->b` be an instance of `a->b` ?

The terminology "type expression" is used for example on page 314 (third edition of the book):

> As sets of types, we look for the intersection of the sets given by
> (a, [Char] ) and  (Int, [b] ) . How can we work out a description of
> this intersection? Before we do this,  we revise and introduce some
> terminology.
>
> Recall that an instance of a type is given by replacing
> a type variable or variables  by type expressions. A type expression
> is a common instance of two type expressions if it  is an instance of
> each expression.
>
> The most general common instance of two expressions
> is a common instance mgci with the property that every other common
> instance is an  instance of mgci.
>
> Now we can describe the
> intersection of the sets given by two type expressions. It  is called
> the unification of the two, which is the most general common instance
> of the  two type expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to think of types as "things", then one can talk about the words we write to describe them, words like `Int` and `Cont (r -> a) (Maybe q)` as a language to describe those things. A similar distinction lies between the number 3 and the Haskell code fragment `3`.

In the same way that `3` is a (value) expression denoting the number 3, `Integer` is a type expression denoting the type of integers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so in this sense `a` and `b` are two different polymorphic type expressions but they refer to the same polymorphic type (namely the any type), is that right ?

Comment: That question is a bit more complex. The type expressions `a` and `b` are certainly different as expressions but actually may be interpreted as malformed ("open") expressions and therefore represent no actual type. What you might prefer to write is `forall a . a` and `forall b . b` which now are well-formed type expressions which both denote the same type. Now, however, it's unclear whether it's proper to call them distinct expressions! You can clearly say that they have different written forms, but since we usually only classify expressions up to alpha-equivalence we may not distinguish them.

Comment: Another way of seeing this is to go from "written expression -> abstract binding tree -> type" instead of straight "written expression -> type". The ABT midpoint is nice as it's a good kind of object for doing lots of work in computer science—you can see ABTs as trees annotated with good notions of "binding" and "variables". ABTs have "built in" alpha equivalence, e.g. two ABTs which differ only in valid renamings of bound variables are the same, so the failure to distinguish `forall a . a` and `forall b . b` has a more explicit cauase.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I am trying to find an example such that two expressions ( or ABTs) are different but then they refer to the same type. I have read TAPL, what is a type expression for example in the simply typed lambda calculus or in System F (page 323, TAP) ? Is there such a thing in these systems ?

Comment: The Haskell type of STLC type expressions is `data Type = Arr Type Type`, or, more interestingly, something like `data Type = Arr Type Type | Star` if you have some basic types. System F augments this type language with variables and binding much like I discussed above. Harper's PFPL talks about ABTs and type languages very nicely and I would suggest taking a look into.

Comment: I think that the types `a` and `b` alone are valid types - not malformed - (albeit types which are not valid top level type signatures in Haskell). They would appear internally when types are skolemized by the typechecker, or when you have a local binding with a type signature (`f :: forall a . a -> a; f x = y where y :: a; y = x`). `a` and `b` signify different types, much like `\x . x` and `\y . y` are the same term up to alpha equivalence, but `x` and `y` are not.

Comment: I was being a little strict to call them malformed, perhaps. In Haskell notation, `a` is shorthand for `forall a . a`, or we could talk about the meaning of `a` "in context" and have it stand in for whatever the contextual meaning of the free variable actually is. But as a bare term it certainly doesn't denote any type!

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Harper's PFPL.